# Find how much filespace specific filetype is taking under a directory?

Tags: bash, debian

I have a samba share with my music on it, and I'd like to find out how much disk space only the mp3 files (not anything mixed in with my music like pictures or videos, or any other filetypes like flac or aac or ogg) are taking up. I've tried baobab, gdmap, and ncdu, and don't really want to basically install all of KDE to try filelight (which doesn't look like it can do this either).

I can get a big list of what all is going to move (`find ~/moremusic -name "*.mp3"`), but AFAIK that's not totally helpful. If I do something like `du -a ~/moremusic | grep ".mp3"` I get a whole big list that each line starts with the filesize in KB. Just have to have that added up and I'll be good to go, but I have no idea the best way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `bash 4.x`

```
shopt -s globstar; du **/*.mp3 | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

With `find`

```
find . -type f -name "*.mp3" -exec du {} + | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

Comment: This is genius, thanks. Added it as a function to my shell.

Answer (score 0):

Gives the total size in bytes:

```
echo $(($(find ~/moremusic -name "*.mp3" -printf %s+)0))
```

Uses find to create a string of separate byte sizes ending with "+". This string, with an ending "0" to keep the shell from complaining about an empty operator, is given to the built-in shell calculator function.